# Nginx ssl error for safari

Tags: nginx, safari, ssl-certificate

I am getting a "safari cant verify the identity of website" pop-up, while connecting to my webserver. However all other browsers chrome, IE, firefox doesnot have any problem in connection. I turned on the debug in conf file and got this:

```
ssl error logs::http check ssl handshake
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 http recv(): 1
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 https ssl handshake: 0x16
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL server name: "www.unitedwifi.com"
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL_get_error: 2
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 reusable connection: 0
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL handshake handler: 0
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL: TLSv1, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=AES(128) Mac=SHA1"
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 reusable connection: 1
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 http wait request handler
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 malloc: 09307C40:1024
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 posix_memalign: 09451B10:256 @16
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL_read: -1
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL_get_error: 2
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 free: 09307C40
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 http wait request handler
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 malloc: 09307C40:1024
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL_read: 242
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL_read: -1
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 SSL_get_error: 2
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 reusable connection: 0
2013/11/01 23:27:59 [debug] 16494#0: *240 posix_memalign: 0944C940:4096 @16

I thought may be its a renegotiation issue with safari.. But I couldn't see anything in the logs regarding that..

Any ideas?
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of browser that I use to connect to "www.unitedwifi.com" I get a certificate error, this is because the certificate presented on the server is only valid for CN=www.mileageplus.com

I may be completely wrong there bit I believe this is why Safari is giving you a cipher-suite but won't actually trust the connection unless you accept it within your keystore/keychain

Comment: the issue I had is in a VPN. my nginx hosts that unitedwifi portal. I use a wildcard ssl certificate for all the connection which is signed by VeriSign not this "mileageplus". Other browsers seems to take that.. I am still not able to debug the exact problem. You may be right but I would like to see corresponding messages in logs. Any thing that you can suggest to debug this better??

Comment: If you are using a Mac then open terminal and use OpenSSL or cUrl. 

The commands would be as follows;
`openssl s_client -connect www.unitedwifi.com:443` 


Or for Curl;
`curl -vvv https://www.unitiedwifi.com` 

I think, both will give you the certificate information that is being picked up as such. You can change the domain name to be anything you see fit.